# Do loop in tidyverse

Tags: loops, tidyverse

I have a data set grouped by clusters and would like to
find the covariance matrix of each pair of clusters.
For example:

```
df %>% 
    filter(clust %in% c(1,2)) %>%
    cov()
```

Is there a way to do so for many clusters and
save the output in a tibble?

The following code run but it is not pretty

```
cv12 <-  
df %>% 
    filter(clust %in% c(1,2)) %>%
    cov() 
cv13 <-  
df %>% 
    filter(clust %in% c(1,3)) %>%
    cov() 
cv14 <-  
df %>% 
    filter(clust %in% c(1,4)) %>%
    cov() 

cv <- rbind(cv12,cv13,cv14)
```

Comment: Could you please share your dataset? You can use `dput`.

Comment: df <- tibble(clust=rep(1:3,each=4),v1=rnorm(12),v2=rnorm(12),v3=rnorm(12))

Comment: cv <- list()
for (i in 1:3){
    df %>% 
    filter(clust %in% c(i,i+1)) %>%
    cov()  -> cv[[i]]
}

cv